# Line through a given point

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Could someone give a proof of "The line through a given point and parallel to a given line can be drawn".

I would be able to do this myself but I am so confused on the wording. As in what are we given initially? A point and a line or just a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're given a line and a point, and you wish to draw a line through that given point parallel to the line that you were given.

This is known as [Playfair's Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair's_axiom) and is equivalent to the [parallel postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) (also known as Euclid's fifth postulate). We can prove that these two are equivalent, but you cannot prove one by itself (many attempts in the past to prove just the parallel postulate have been made however).

Comment: so the point given is not on the line given?

Comment: If the point was actually on the line given, then the only line parallel to the original line would be itself, which isn't that interesting to consider.